# How do I find the half-line equation for the locus $\operatorname{arg}(z - a) = \frac{-3\pi}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, locus

So there are a locus composed of points $m$ that is $z$ and it's a half-line:

$\operatorname{arg}(z - a) = \frac{-3\pi}{4}$

$a = - 1 + i$

The problem is that I have no idea how to find out the equation(Half-line equation I mean)

Comment: The condition means that $z=a+r\, e^{-i\,3 \pi/4}$ with $r \in \mathbb R^+$. How exactly you write it depends on what form you want the equation to be in.

Comment: @dxiv I have no idea what that means ): so how do I find the equation? I don't get it.

Comment: How do you write the equation of a half-line (*any* half-line)? There are different ways to describe the same half-line, and it is not clear from the question which is the form you are looking for.

Comment: @dxiv I think I didn't write some important info, can I remove the post and repeat?

Comment: You don't have to remove the question, especially after answers were posted. If you only need to clarify details of the same question you can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4159493/edit) the post, otherwise if it's a different question you can make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the half-line from $a= (a_x, a_y)$ in the direction
$\theta= -\frac{3\pi}{4}$.  So the Cartesian equation is $y- a_y= m(x- a_x)$ where m is the slope of the line: $m= tan(3\pi/4)= $$\frac{sin(-3\pi/4)}{cos(-3\pi/4)}=$$ -\frac{sin(3\pi/4)}{cos(3\pi/4)}$.

$sin(3\pi/4)= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $cos(3\pi/4)= -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ so this is -1.

Comment: If we do this then we would find it $y + x = 0$ right? But the book didn't find it that at all. The solution in the book was $y + x = 2$ Also how did you get that "Cartesian equation" I don't understand.